# querying on kinda EVA like model

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

we have this table and some data

[image: Table schema]

[image: Table data]

in some scenario we need to get the **Entities** that they have a property that have special **Value** and the property itself is not important.

the prob is we want to get entities that they have property where value is equal to 1 and also have a property with a value of 2

in a simple way we need something like this :

> SELECT Entity_Id FROM table WHERE Value = 1 AND Value = 2

this query returns nothing because the **Value column** only have 1 value ^_^

actually we need something like this

> SELECT Entity_Id FROM table
>
> GROUP BY Entity_Id
>
> HAVING Value = 1 AND Value = 2

MsSql do not support this query, u have to use an aggregate function. OTL

because in this scenario all filters set on **Value** column
u can parsing the first query to something like this :

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Entity_Id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE Value = 1 and Order_Id = outerTable.Order_Id) 
    * 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE Value = 2 and Order_Id = outerTable.Order_Id) as xxx
FROM table AS outerTable
```

currently what i do is get the first query predicates and pars it to third form query.

**EDIT :** 
the filters that set on first query is optional and sent by user without knowing the background structure , he think that all of properties is saved as columns for this entity 
thats why i parse the AND to

(subQry(filter1) * subQry(filter2) * .... * subQry(filter N))

OR to

(subQry(filter1) + subQry(filter2) + ..... + subQry(filter N))

looking for a better solution ^_^"

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two other ways, in addition to what the other answers already mention:

```
select entity_id from table where value = 1
intersect
select entity_id from table where value = 2


select t1.entity_id from table t1
join table t2 on t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id
where t1.value = 1 and t2.value = 2
```

Comment: using intersect to AND and union for OR is good but i think it wont work for optional filters , but I'm gonna test it. thx

Comment: I was going to propose the `INTERSECT` version. this will also remove duplicate values.

Comment: @PhilipKelley I like `intersect` as it's compact and really easy to understand. The performance might not be on par with some other solutions though.

Comment: well its work ^_^, and the parsing where clause  is easy and result query is clean also its easy now to handle predicate like (x=1 and x=2)or(x=1 and (z=3 or x=4)) . tyvm

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT Entity_Id
FROM table
WHERE Value in (1, 2)
GROUP BY Entity_Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 2;
```

Comment: the filters that set on first query is optional and send by user, that's why i parse AND to (qry * qry) and pars OR  to (qry + qry)

Comment: This would return Entities that had two values set to 1 and no values set to 2.

Comment: @PhilipKelley, you are wrong. This will return entities which have both 1 and 2

Comment: @PhilipKelley . . . you are wrong.  Look at the `distinct` in the `having` clause.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Subtle! (and points out the advantage of in-line comments...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the check with exists clause, with something like this:

```
SELECT Entity_Id 
FROM table t1
WHERE Value = 1 AND 
exists (
  select 1 
  from table t2 
  where t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id and 
  t2.Value = 2)
```